# I want to Create a csv file containing 1000 rows for which random number is generated

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Problem: Create a text/csv file containing 1000 rows with the following fields/columns:
StudentID: unique identifier 1:1000
Score: Random number between 40-100
Date: Any random date within the last 20 days. Eg: 18/11/2022
Description: Get a random word from a list of 10 words of your choice
Ethnicity: Randomly assign an ethnicity(google if you don't know meaning)
Subject: Randomly assign one from 10 subjects. eg: Calculus, Statistics, Databases,
Hobby: Randomly assign one from a list of 10 hobbies
Interest: Randomly assign one from a list of 10 interests. Eg: music, nonfiction, debate, swimming,

```
import csv import random

fields = ['Student Id', 'score', 'date', 'Description',
'Ethinicity', 'Subject', 'Hobby', 'Intrest']
description_list=('Delhi','Noida','goa','varansi','Assam','Kerala','Kolkata','Shilong','Bangluru','Gujrat')
Ethinicity_list=('Sikh','Kashmiri','Rajput','Bhramin','Kayasth','Adiwasi','Odia','Maratha')
Subject_list=('English','Maths','Economics','Hindi','French','Zoology','Chemistry','Physics','Social
Science','Python')
Hobby_list=('Reading','Swimming','Cycling','Biking','Gaming','Sleeping','Teaching','Cricket','Shooting','Talking')
Intrest_list=('Watching
TV','Esports','Football','MotoRacing','Music','Painting','Sketching','Cooking','Cars','Comedy')
data = [
    [random.randint(1, 1000),random.randint(40,100),'__',random.choice(description_list),random.choice(Ethinicity_list),random.choice(Subject_list),random.choice(Hobby_list),random.choice(Intrest_list)]
]

filename = "assignment.csv"

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:     
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

This senerates a single row of required data.
I want to generate 1000 rows with same data.

Comment: Why don't you repeat the same code that generates one line of data and adds it to the list `data` in a loop 1000 times?

Comment: Write to a file the first line (csv headers/columns) and then loop a 1000 times over writing a single line into the file.

Answer (score 0):

you could use list comprehensions together with pandas dataframes something along the lines of this:

```
import pandas as pd

# randomly chooses an element of your list/tuple 1000 times
description_choices = [random.choice(description_list) for _ in range(1000)]
...

# create table with random data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': description_choices, 
        ...
        })

df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Comment: There's no need to use pandas. They already seem to know how to use the `csv` module.